# Use variable to send data with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm using jquery AJAX to instant save things, however when an ID already exists it will give a hidden element with data in it. Which is already given as the 'right' syntax for `$.ajax` data.

I'm returning something like this:

`{'km' : '43223432', 'id' : '2', 'date' : '15-01-2014'}`

All values can be different ofcourse.

However; if this is returned, the user can click on a button to 'overwrite' the data. Data is stored in: `$(".errorLogContent")`

```
    var text = $(".errorLogContent").text(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../uitvoer/overschijf.php",
    data: text
});
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't send data without parameter name... let's say the name of the parameter will be `param`

do it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../uitvoer/overschijf.php",
      data: { 
         myparam:text //set it with a parameter name
      }
});
```

in overschijf.php file you will receive the `text` as

```
$_POST['myparam'];
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Not exactly what I'm searching for, but this seems the nearest approach for this question that works. Thanks!

Comment: ok goodluck =) just tell us if you will encounter any problems

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../uitvoer/overschijf.php",
    data: {
       data: text
    }
});
```